# Aggregate Kubernetes liveness probe responses

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

My application has a `/health` Http endpoint, configured for Kubernetes liveness check probe. The API returns a json, containing the health indicators.

Kubernetes only cares about the returned http status, but I would like to store the json responses in Prometheus for monitoring purposes.

Is it possible to catch the response once Kubernetes calls the API? I do not want to add the feature to the application itself but use an external component.

What is the recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

**Answering to what you've asked:**

1. Make a sidecar that calls `localhost:port/health` every `N` seconds and stores the most recent reply. `N` should be equal to the prometheus scraping interval for accurate results.
2. A sidecar then exposes the most recent reply in the form of metric in `/metrics` endpoint, on a separate port of a pod. You could use https://github.com/prometheus/client_python to implement the sidecar. *Prometheus exporter sidecar* is actually a widely used pattern, try searching for it.
3. Point Prometheus to service `/metrics` endpoint, which is now served by a sidecar, on a separate port. You will need a separate port in a `Service` object, to point to your sidecar port. The scraping interval can be adjusted at this stage, to be in sync with your `N`, or otherwise, just adjust `N`. For `scrape_config` details refer to: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#service

   If you need an automatic Prometheus target discovery, say you have a bunch of deployments like this and their number varies - refer to my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64269434/923620

**Proposing a simpler solution:**

1. In your app ensure you log everything you return in `/health`
2. Implement centralized logging (log aggregation): https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/
3. Use a log processor, e.g. ELK, to query/analyze the results.

Comment: Thanks, these are really good suggestions, however, I would like to avoid calling the API more than needed. As Kubernetes also calls the API, I would like to catch that event - not sure that is feasible and supported by Kubernetes in any way

Comment: I think this answer is still actual then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599554/923620

Comment: Be careful raising log levels of a kubelet, as it will apply to everything you run on the cluster, not only this app - the amount of logs can be huge. Popular log collectors often collecting kubelet logs out of the box, see https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/fluent-bit (`systemdUnit` variable)